# Laravel Database Seeder extremely slow

Tags: database, apache, performance, laravel

I have a simple TestSeeder class which seeds some tables, nothing special.

This seeder runs fine (a few milliseconds) on another pc I'm using. The problem is, on the current pc I'm using, the seeder is extremely slow. I saved some timestamps so you can see how long it takes:

```
Truncated all tables. Took: 0 seconds.
User & Question table seeded. Took: 23 seconds for 150 rows.
Answer table seeded. Took: 15 seconds for 451 rows.
Statistics table seeded. Took: 5 seconds for 151 rows.
Score table seeded. Took: 13 seconds for 3 rows.
Total time: 56 seconds
```

As some people request, I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in several config files, but that didn't work.

Im using a Wamp server.

Is there anything I can do to improve performance? Thanks in advance!